# Why does this Hidden Markov Model make this prediction?

Tags: c#, machine-learning, hidden-markov-models, accord.net

I am trying to understand how HMM works, but I think I am missing some crucial part of information that I cannot identify. I want it to predict the next "feature"/"symbol" based on a given sequence.

```
        int[][] sequences =
        {
            new[] { 10001, 15, 1, 0, 0, 10002 },
            new[] { 10002, 0, 1, 0, 15, 10001 },
            new[] { 101, 15, 0, 0, 0, 101},
            new[] { 101, 0, 0, 0, 15, 101 },
            new[] { 114, 15, 0, 1, 0, 114 },
            new[] { 114, 0, 0, 1, 15, 114 },
            new[] { 10001, 15, 1, 0, 0, 10002 },
            new[] { 10002, 0, 1, 0, 15, 10001 },
        };

        var teacher = new BaumWelchLearning()
        {
            Topology = new Forward(6),
            Tolerance = 0.0001,
        };

        HiddenMarkovModel hmm = teacher.Learn(sequences);

        // Gives 15 instead of 114
        int[] prediction = hmm.Predict(observations: new[] { 114, 15, 0, 1, 0 }, next: 1);
```

The next character for "114, 15, 0, 1, 0" should be 114, yet the prediction is 15. Am I doing something wrong with the topology? Do I need to define something differently?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

u can't use statistic/probabilistic to  predict one single realization. The theory make sense when u use it in many occurrences. In your case 
call :

```
int[] prediction = hmm.Predict(observations: new[] { 114, 15, 0, 1, 0 },   next: 1);
```

many times and see what's next observations probs. really is ...

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Do you mean that calling the Predict many times will help? I don't think so. I tried to feed the model with more occurencies of the same sequence, still the result is the same. That doesn't mean of course I am doing the right thing and the implementation of the HMM is wrong. I just don't know exactly how it is meant to work.

Comment: The difference could be caused by differences in methods to calculate p(15 | 114, 15, 0, 1, 0) and p(114 | 114, 15, 0, 1, 0)

Comment: The next character for "114, 15, 0, 1, 0" should be 114, yet the prediction is 15. this just mean p(15 | 114, 15, 0, 1, 0) is 'some how' bigger/better than 'yours' p(114 | 114, 15, 0, 1, 0) .. but 15 still can be happen ... IF it has non zero prob

Comment: so you mean that my small dataset creates a bias based on the occurencies of 15 in all the sequences?

Comment: yup, and to overcome it, you should dig deeper to  the heart of the algorithm of prediction and decision involved